# How to correctly extract/composite custom widgets and handle their child fields

Tags: flutter

In my widget tree, I have several `TextField` widgets. All have the same decoration but different `onChanged` actions:

```
Widget _buildTextField() {
  return TextField (
    decoration: InputDecoraction(
      border: OutlineInputBorder()
    ),
    onChanged: (text) {
      doSth();
    }
  );
}
```

---

Now I want to reduce the code duplication and was trying to extract the `TextField` with the duplicated `decoration` field into a `CustomTextField`. I read that with Flutter composition is over inheritance, so I tried to compose it this way:

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomTextFieldState createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(     //   <-- the decoration field
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

At the other side I did:

```
Widget _buildTextField() {
  return CustomTextField (               //   <-- new CustomTextField without decoration
    onChanged: (text) {                  //   <-- Problem: "Parameter is not defined"
      doSth();
    }
  );
}
```

But now the `onChanged` call is not accepted. So, what is the correct way to extract own widgets and handle the child fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a callback function

```
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onChange;

  const CustomTextField({Key key, this.onChange}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomTextFieldState createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          //   <-- the decoration field
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
        onChanged: widget.onChange,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and then

```
  child: CustomTextField(
    onChange: (item) {
      print(item);
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what I missed!